# Advanced SQL SUM COLUMN FROM A SAME TABLE

Tags: sql, sum

I have this table...

```
+-----+--------+------+-----+-----+
|categ| nAME   | quan |IDUNQ|   ID|
+-----+--------+------+-----+-----+
|   1 | Z      |    3 |   1 |  15 |
|   1 | A      |    3 |   2 |  16 |
|   1 | B      |    3 |   3 |  17 |
|   2 | Z      |    2 |   4 |  15 |
|   2 | A      |    2 |   5 |  16 |
|   3 | Z      |    1 |   6 |  15 |
|   3 | B      |    1 |   7 |  17 |
|   2 | Z      |    1 |   8 |  15 |
|   2 | C      |    4 |   8 |  15 |
|   1 | D      |    1 |   8 |  15 |
+-----+--------+------+-----+-----+
```

I need to get the *Z of category 1 + Z of category 2 - Z of category 3*

For example, *(3+3-1) = 5   ==>  3 of cat 1,  3 of cat 2, 1 of cat 3*

The final result should be...

```
Z ==> 5
A ==> 5
B ==> 2
C ==> 4
```

Comment: Where does `C ==> 4` come from in your "final result"? There are no `C` `nAMES` (your spelling) in your sample data. Please try again, and be a little more specific. If your only values for `categ` are `1`, `2`, and `3`, and the only `nAME` values are `A`, `B`, and `Z`, this is a very simple query. If the values can be different than those, then you've not provided anywhere near enough information or sample data.

Comment: sorry, i forget some rows   this is final table...

but runs in sql server
http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/51ee5/4

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Note: I'm assuming the data for "C" from your example was mistakenly omitted.

```
SELECT nAME, SUM(CASE categ WHEN 3 THEN 0-quan ELSE quan END) AS quan
FROM theTable
GROUP BY nAME
```

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/dfb35/2)

Comment: It might not be a mistake, should be an omission. Your answer is brilliant

Comment: sorry, i omit a row, this is final table.

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/51ee5/4

SQL SERVER 2008

Answer (score -2):

```
SELECT name, SUM(quan) AS sum
FROM   tableName
GROUP BY name, categ
```

This should work.

Comment: This will work in MySQL since the MySQL Group By clause is more forgiving. A database like Oracle will expect you to select categ in the SELECT clause.

Comment: -1. This doesn't answer the question asked, which was how to add two categories and **subtract** the third. There's no subtraction - you didn't answer a critical (and very important) part of the question at all.